# Save browser action (popup) react state per tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm using react in my chrome extension and I'm running into problems with saving the state for the browser action popup which gets reset every time the window closes.

The browser popup initiates some calls to the server and then returns the answer to the content script, based on the progress of the calls the state changes

**popup.js**

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, loading: true });
    content_script
        .GetData()
        .then(list => {
          // Make multiple calls to the server
          }).then(data => {
                content_script.DoSomethingWithData(data)
                this.setState({ ...this.state, loading: false });
          });
```

I figured I will have to move this code to a background script (unless there is a better solution) since closing this window will also interrupt the calls - but how can I update and save the store of the popup window per tab from the background script?

Comment: The popup page environment exists only when it's shown so indeed the most reliable solution is to let the background script handle the [potentially] long-running tasks. Simply save the state in a map keyed on a tab id.

Comment: Thanks, for good response times should I be using a storage (chrome.storage) or should it be saved in the background script?

Comment: Depends on how big those delays are. Also, if your background script is persistent:false you'll have to either use chrome.storage or intentionally keep the background script alive. Or use the synchronous localStorage + JSON.stringify/parse.